# Xcode does not create file

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, nsfilemanager, filehandle

I'm writing an app that saves text to a CSV file. But I can't find the file at the path after trying it in the simulator.

Here is the code:

```
    #import "protboViewController.h"

@interface protboViewController ()

@end

@implementation protboViewController
@synthesize email;

- (IBAction)retractKeyboard:(id)sender{
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}
- (IBAction)saveInfo:(id)sender {
    NSString *resultLine=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",
                          self.email.text];

    NSString *docPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *mailLista=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"elista.csv"];

                          if  (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:docPath]) {
                              [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:mailLista contents:nil attributes:nil];
                          }
                          NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:mailLista];
                          [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
                          [fileHandle writeData:[resultLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                          [fileHandle closeFile];
                            self.email.text=@"";
                          NSLog(@"info saved");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I get the "info saved" prompt in the console but when I go to the "iPhone Simulator" folder and check there is no file.

Also, how can I export this file to my computer from a device?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Now I have it creating a file and adding one line of text, but if I try to add one line of text the whole file is replaced with a new file with one line of text.

```
#import "protboViewController.h"

@interface protboViewController ()

@end

@implementation protboViewController
@synthesize email;


- (IBAction)retractKeyboard:(id)sender{
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}
- (IBAction)saveInfo:(id)sender {
    NSString *resultLine=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",
                          self.email.text];

    NSArray *docPath =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *docDirectory = [docPath objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *mailLista=[docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"elista.csv"];

    NSError *csvError = NULL;

    BOOL written = [resultLine writeToFile:mailLista atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&csvError];

    if (!written)
        NSLog(@"write failed, error=%@", csvError);
    else
        NSLog(@"Saved! File path =", mailLista);

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I searched for an answer and I found something that said "Since you are not using the for loop make sure and declare outputString in your header file. Initialize it in your viewDidLoad and then you will be able to append to it."

How do I declare it in my header file and what should i initialize in viewDidLoad?

Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your "protboViewController.h"

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* mailLista;
```

Add this to your viewDidLoad:

```
NSString *docPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
self.mailLista = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"elista.csv"];
if  (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:docPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:self.mailLista contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
```

finally change your saveInfo to something like this:

```
NSString *resultLine=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", self.email.text];

NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:self.mailLista];
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
[fileHandle writeData:[resultLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[fileHandle closeFile];
self.email.text=@"";

NSLog(@"Saved! File path =%@", self.mailLista);
```

that's the way I did it previously in one of my own apps

Comment: No, that is not a valid change. The OP is trying to append to an existing file, if it is already there. Your change would always overwrite any existing file.

Comment: @rmaddy you're right, I didn't notice his intention.

without my change, did it at least print the correct path?

Comment: @KevinGriesbach I have made it so that it creates a file now but instead of adding a new line it overwrites everything. I will edit my first post and if you could take a look at it I would be very grateful.

Comment: I just updated my answer, give it a try - though it looks pretty similar to your first attempt.